# Why the following integral is $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I have the following integral and I know that is $0$ but why?
$$\int _T \frac{1}{(z^2+4)(z^2+16)^n)}dz$$
 where $n$ is natural and $T$ is the triangle in $(-i,1,-1)$ and $z$ is complex number

I know that is $0$ because the function inside integral it doesn't cancel in any point inside the triangle

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's Theorem? The function is analytic except at $\pm 2i$ and these points are outside the triangle so the integral is $0$.

Comment: So any integral that doesn't cancel in any point inside the integration domain is 0 conform Cauchy's Theorem?

Comment: Unbalanced parentheses: never a good sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: By Cauchy's theorem, if $f(z)$ is analytic on the region bounded by the closed curve $\gamma$, then $\oint_{\gamma}f(z)\operatorname dz=0$.